# How to hide the Access 2016 Home ribbon tab through VBA?

Tags: vba, ribbon, ms-access-2016

I'm looking for a way to hide the standard Home tab on the ribbon in my Access 2016 application. I would like to do this from VBA. Hiding the complete ribbon isn't an option. I've tried to do this using the commandbars-collection, but without any positive results.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Application.LoadCustomUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194416.aspx) method but the process is a little involved on initial setup. Below are the directions and the same steps when creating new custom tabs:

1. Create or load the custom UI xml (a well-formed xml document) and then pass it as a string to method, giving the ribbon a name such as *HideHome*:

   ```
   Public Function CustomRibbon()
       Dim customXML As String

       customXML = "<customUI xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office" _
                   & "/2009/07/customui"">" _
                   & "  <ribbon startFromScratch=""false"">" _
                   & "    <tabs>" _
                   & "      <tab idMso=""TabHomeAccess"" visible=""false"" />" _
                   & "    </tabs>" _
                   & "  </ribbon>" _
                   & "</customUI>"

       Application.LoadCustomUI "HideHome", customXML
   End Function
   ```
2. Call this function or subroutine in an OnOpen or OnLoad trigger event of **opening** form or in a macro named **AutoExec**. This step is important as you cannot re-load or change the ribbon once it is visible else an error will emerge so be sure it is part of opening automation.
3. The very first time you open database, nothing will happen because you must first select the created ribbon under options. After first opening database with above first two steps handled, under File / Options / Current Database, scroll down to *Ribbon and Tab Options*, select your new ribbon name (the one created and named in Step #1) in drop down field.
4. Close and re-open the database and Home tab should no longer be visible on ribbon. Going forward in changing the same named ribbon, you can skip 3.

**I know above steps works for MS Access 2007-2013, hopefully more or less the same in 2016.